# aurigma uploader context menu not showing

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, uploader, aurigma

How to add a context menu in aurigma uploader. I want to add select all and deselect all option.
I have read this documentation  ( http://www.aurigma.com/docs/us8/JA_AllMembers_T_J_$au_contextMenu.htm ) and I have tried this below coding. But, nothing appear in aurigma uploader plugin?

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var uploader = $au.uploader({
                      id: 'Uploader1',
                      width: '950px',
                      height: '500px',
                      licenseKey: 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX',
                      enableDescriptionEditor: false,
                      enableRotation: false,
                      activeXControl: {
                          codeBase: 'Scripts/Uploader8.cab',
                          codeBase64: 'Scripts/Uploader8_x64.cab'
                      },
                      javaControl: {
                          codeBase: 'Scripts/Uploader8.jar'
                      },
                      uploadSettings: {
                          actionUrl: 'upload.php',
                          //redirectUrl: 'gallery.php',
                          filesPerPackage: 1       
                      },
                      converters: [
                          { mode: '*.*=SourceFile' }
                      ],
                      folderPane: {
                          height: 370
                      },
                      uploadPane: {
                          viewMode: 'List'
                      },
                    contextMenu: {
                        addFilesText: "Add files",
                        uncheckAllText: "Uncheck all"
                    },
                      detailsViewColumns: {
                          infoText: ''
                      },
                      paneItem: {
                          showFileNameInThumbnailsView: true
                      },
                      imageEditor: {
                        enableCrop: false
                      }
                    });

                    var ip = $au.installationProgress(uploader);
                    ip.progressImageUrl('Images/installation_progress.gif');
                    ip.progressCssClass('ip-progress');
                    ip.instructionsCssClass('ip-instructions');

                    uploader.writeHtml();
                  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Aurigma.

The “check all” feature is enabled by default. If you open a folder in the folder view and expand the context menu, you will see this option there. It allows you to add all files in the folder to the upload list. The property ContextMenu.CheckAllText is used to change caption for the menu item.

[image]

Are you expecting some other behavior for this menu item or you don’t see it in the context menu?